# AutoHotkey Run script while holding down key

Tags: script, autohotkey, code

I need help with a script, i want it to only run while im holding down a key. Heres the script:

```
;If you use this, you have to use absolute screen coordinates.
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen

;Suppose a 100x100 px bounding box for your game inventory.
;Eg., from (500, 500) to (600, 600)
w::
{
    ;Get current Mouse coords
    MouseGetPos, xCurrent ,yCurrent

    ;Calculate future Mouse coords
    xMoved := xCurrent
    yMoved := yCurrent - 35

    ;Check if the future mouse postion will be
    ;below the top border of your bounding box, 
    ;aka still inside it, after it has moved.
    ;If so, proceed and move the mouse,
    ;otherwise do nothing.
MouseGetPos, CoordXRec, CoordYRec
        MouseMove, xMoved, yMoved


if(yMoved < 503 && yMoved > 350 && yMoved > 360){
MouseMove 1846, 166
}
if(yMoved < 145){
MouseMove, %CoordXRec%, %CoordYRec%, 0
}
if(yMoved < 718 && yMoved < 720 && yMoved > 680){
MouseMove 1771, 671
}
return  
}
s::
{
    ;Get current Mouse coords
    MouseGetPos, xCurrent ,yCurrent

    ;Calculate future Mouse coords
    xMoved := xCurrent
    yMoved := yCurrent +35

    ;Check if the future mouse postion will be
    ;below the top border of your bounding box, 
    ;aka still inside it, after it has moved.
    ;If so, proceed and move the mouse,
    ;otherwise do nothing.

        MouseMove, xMoved, yMoved

if(yMoved > 285 && yMoved < 360){
MouseMove 1773, 526
}
if(yMoved > 697 && yMoved < 715){
MouseMove 1772, 736
}
return
}
a::
{
    ;Get current Mouse coords
    MouseGetPos, xCurrent ,yCurrent

    ;Calculate future Mouse coords
    xMoved := xCurrent -40
    yMoved := yCurrent 

    ;Check if the future mouse postion will be
    ;below the top border of your bounding box, 
    ;aka still inside it, after it has moved.
    ;If so, proceed and move the mouse,
    ;otherwise do nothing.
    if (xMoved > 1740) {
        MouseMove, xMoved, yMoved
    }
return  
}
d::
{
    ;Get current Mouse coords
    MouseGetPos, xCurrent ,yCurrent

    ;Calculate future Mouse coords
    xMoved := xCurrent +40
    yMoved := yCurrent 

    ;Check if the future mouse postion will be
    ;below the top border of your bounding box, 
    ;aka still inside it, after it has moved.
    ;If so, proceed and move the mouse,
    ;otherwise do nothing.
    if (xMoved < 1917) {
        MouseMove, xMoved, yMoved
    }
return  
}
```

Basicly you control the mouse with WASD and theres some other functionality to it aswell but i want to make it so that you have to hold down a key in order to move. Thanks!

Comment: What key do you want to use?  A modifier?

Comment: I have a code template I use when I want something to loop *until* I press a key. On each iteration of the loop, I use `GetKeyState` to check that key. You could probably do the same thing with whatever key you want to hold down. Put a loop inside each hotkey that loops infinitely until `GetKeyState` detects that the key state is `U` and then breaks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to holding down the key for that action and having some delay before the action activates (vs. holding down some other key such as a modifier), you could do something with `GetKeyState` as mentioned already.

The following set of code could be inserted or called as a function from each hotkey definition.  You can change the delay settings as needed to be suitable for what you're trying to do (or it may not do exactly what you want to do and may be klunky for you if it's not what you were thinking of, but the original post was pretty vague).

Insert this code at the beginning of each hotkey definition and it will require you to hold down that hotkey for a certain amount of time before it activates, otherwise the keystroke will be sent regularly.  You will also need to add a `$` in front of the hotkey definition so the `Send` statement doesn't re-trigger the hotkey definition twice in a row and cause an immediate execution (since this precursor function will send the same key as the hotkey if the user just briefly presses the key and doesn't hold it down).

Since the hotkey variables are generic you can also just put this in a separate function call so you don't have to repeat the code and then just call the function for each hotkey.  Maybe this will give you some ideas even if it's not exactly what you want.

```
$a::
{
    ; make these global or static as desired so they don't have to be reassigned for each function call
    holdDelay:=300          ; time to wait before activation (or conversely, must release before this time to send a keystroke)
    repeatDelay:=700        ; max time to detect a repeat event--must be bigger than holdDelay or won't work

    ; if we just triggered this key last time and it's been less than the repeat delay,
    ; bypass the hold-down check and skip directly to desired function for moving the mouse
    If Not ((A_ThisHotkey=A_PriorHotkey) && (A_TimeSincePriorHotkey<repeatDelay)) {

        trimmedHotkey:=Trim(A_ThisHotkey, "$")  ; get rid of preceding $ so we can detect and send just the keystroke

        startTick:=A_TickCount                              ; init timer
        While GetKeyState(trimmedHotkey, "P")               ; Loop while key is pressed down, otherwise exit    
        && !(heldDown:=(A_TickCount-startTick)>holdDelay)   ; check for helddown/timeout (user held the key down)
            Sleep 10                                        ; wait a few ms...

        If !heldDown {                  ; if user didn't hold the key down, send it back as a keystroke

            SendInput % trimmedHotkey
            Return 
        }

    }

    ; Rest of the code goes here
```